# Select all user accounts that have the same email from database

Tags: php

We have a database with around 900 accounts. A few clients have more than one account but they all have the same email. How can I effectively let the client select the account to view when logging in.

I have posted a screenshot here to help explain this. I am already logging in users with single account, the multiple account dont seem to know which user to login.

http://prntscr.com/ehttj4

Any help would be appretiated. I will post some code if needed.

Comment: What particular problem you have? You know, selecting records from a db and then displaying them is the most trivial task in the web-development.

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking. Can you please edit your question? What do you mean with "How can I effectively let the client select the account to view when logging in." ... what is to view when logging in? Also, why you don't simply implement a check if the e-mail is already registered? That would help a lot. Also, you should take care about what you're posting on the web. You just posted a screenshot of data (customer data?!) on a internetsite... Always think twice about that before doing it.

Comment: Okay my problem is that after logging in the user goes to a page that shows them some account info. That works fine. But I cant login users who have more then one account with us. Does that make more sense? So maybe if someone can help to let those users login and then select which account they want to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SysID, emails, COUNT(emails) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY emails 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY SysID DESC;
```

Use this query to get counts of duplicate email there in the table, in your `SysID` order.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this sorted it out.